# Move a object according to a table edges

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x, game-physics

I want to use swipe gesture to move the red object according to the table edges like below:

[image]

I want to implement it by Box2D & Cocos2D-x. However, I don't find any joints that satisfy my requirement. I know Prismatic joint, but it allows a objects can only move along a specified axis.

Thank you for reading my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik the only (easy) way to constrain a dynamic (or kinematic) body to move only on two axis would be enclose the body in static bodies like images below.

First example uses static polygon bodies (green) and the second one uses edge bodies to limit the circle movement.

[image]
[image]

However you might also use the SetTransform method to force the position of the body (not always recommended but might be a good option depending of your needs). Then you can completely control the movement of the body.

Comment: Thank you Laurent. I will try your idea

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind to try to build the white boxes with physic boundary and bind the ball to a very tiny body, using the collision detection?

Comment: Thank M.ding. I want to move the ball on the black lines according to a swipe gesture of finger (up, down, left, right)